# How to strip whitespace off of a returned field from DRF model Serializer?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, whitespace, trim

I have the following code for my DRF serializer:

```
class ObjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = models.MyModel
    fields = ('field1', 'field2')
```

My query code looks like this:

```
class MyAPI(ListAPIView):
http_method_names = ['get']
serializer_class = ObjectSerializer

def get_queryset(self):
    queryset = MyModel.objects.values('field1', 'field2').filter(someField='SomeValue').all()
    return queryset
```

field1 is a char field with trailing whitespace. I am trying to remove all of that trailing whitespace in the query set. How can I go about doing that? I tried passing in the `extra_kwargs = {"content": {"trim_whitespace": True}}` statement into my serializer but it doesn't trim the whitespace on the field. Is what I am doing wrong obvious and I am just missing it?

Edit: Here is what the model code looks like:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
field1 = models.CharField(db_column='FIELD1', max_length=24)  # Field name made lowercase.
field2 = models.CharField(db_column='FIELD2', max_length=60, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.

class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = 'mytable'
```

Comment: content is of what type? `trim_whitespace` is only valid for charfield and should be passed in the field definition not in extra_kwargs

Comment: Yes, the field is a Char field. so would I have to define the field definition in the serializer and use the trim whitespace keyword argument there?

Comment: yes, you need to

Comment: The docs say it is the default behavior so you may be having a different case. Can you give an example of a value in your db with whitespace that is not getting trimmed?

Comment: So the weird thing is both field1 and field2 are character fields. Field2's whitespace is being properly stripped off. Field1 isn't. Any idea on what the issue could be?

Comment: post the model. It's hard to tell the difference between the fields without knowing how they're defined

Comment: Ok, posted a copy of the model.

Comment: Well that's weird. What are the values you populate them with? or is the DB already populated? can you show an example?